# How do access a JQuery function inside a scope in another Jquery file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to refactor a big JQuery file into smaller ones, but one of the things is I have to be able to call functions inside another JQuery file, but I cant get it to work. So how do I change this code so I can call someFunction inside File1.js from from File2.js?

```
//File1.js
(function (s_diary, $, undefined) {

function someFunction()
{
    alert("Yay");
}

} (window.s_diary= window.s_diary|| {}, jQuery));

//File2.js
(function (s_one, $, undefined) {

function someFunction()
{
    s_diary.someFunction();
}

} (window.s_one= window.s_one|| {}, jQuery));
```

Comment: You can't; that's the point of such *private* variables.

Comment: Why is http://pastebin.com/mqSBrJ3j then able to call the init from outside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at it more closely, formatting, comments, and changes to show point:

```
(function (s_diary, $, undefined) {
  // the someFunction function is private to this function
  // it has the same scope as a function parameter or local var
  function someFunction() {
    alert("Yay");
  }
  // but since all functions are just objects...
  // someFunction is now *exposed* as window.s_diary.someFunction
  // see below for why window.s_diary is modified
  s_diary.someFunction = someFunction
}(window.s_diary = window.s_diary || {}, jQuery));
```

Note that last `(...)` bit *invokes* the function-object previously defined and passes in the object (creating it if needed) known by the name `window.s_diary`. Then *inside* the function the "window.s_diary" object *is mutated*. Remember that `window` is the *global namespace* and is thus available to *all scrips within a single page context*. (Just make sure they are run in the correct order.)

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can do it like this, it is called "revealed module pattern" if I recall correctly:

```
var file1 = (function (s_diary, $, undefined) {

function someFunction()
{
    alert("Yay");
};
return{
    someFunction: someFunction
};
} ());

var file2 = (function (s_one, $, undefined) {

function someFunction()
{
    file1.someFunction();
}

} (window.s_one= window.s_one|| {}, jQuery));
```